# Browser Privacy Settings - How can I ask the user to enable pop-ups on my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, web

Some websites, especially banks, are able to show a permission balloon at the top of the URL asking the user if he wants to enable pop-ups to the current website.

This is an example with Flash:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKwM3.png)

Comment: Are you looking for notifications your site can send to your browser?
This can be done using the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API).
The request itself is handled by the browser, which asks you to allow/disallow notifications.

Comment: @c11o No. It's because on my code I'm using a AJAX request that returns a "window.open(url,"_blank");"

As far as I've read here, this is the reason why the browser blocks the page, because the "windows.open" is on a response, not on a direct action (like a button click).

And the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API) doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: You can't open another window without user interaction...accept it and design app with that in mind

Comment: @charlietfl I'm aware of that, but it's a very specific function in the system. All I need is something to ask the user if he wants to enable the pop-up on my "page".

Comment: Why can't you simply show a link that lets user open it themselves? Will be more intuitive user experience also